# How do I run Commodore 64 games on classicreload.com?

Tags: emulation, commodore-64

On the website classicreload.com, there many Commodorore 64 games, but every time I try to run one I get to the Commodore terminal, and I can't find how to run the game.

Comment: What browser do you use to open the game pages? What version of the browser you have? Do you see content permission question at the top, next to the URL address? I did ever use once the webpage, it worked, now opened this link and works (so at least I can confirm they work correctly)

Comment: @Sonic I use latest Firefox. Didn't see any message. The game just doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

The website seems misconfigured. Just use the games at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary_c64_games).